# Determine Process in multiprocessing.Pool still active?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

## Background

I have some code that looks like this:

```py
import datetime
import multiprocessing

def my_function(a, b, c):
    c.append(a)
    # A cool function that takes a long time and returns a lot of data
    c.remove(a)
    return (random_tuple, very_large_list_of_data)

def main():
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    prev_one_minute_passed = False
    large_list_a = list(range(100)) # ignore that this isn't pythonic, it's an example
    large_list_b = [2] * 100
    l = [] # this is actually handled with a multiprocessing.manager, but
           # it's easier to conceptualize as a plain list.

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=99) as pool:
        out_results = pool.starmap_async(my_cool_function, [(a, b, l) for (a, b) in zip(a, b)])

        while not out_results.ready():
            # do some nifty logging
            if ((datetime.datetime.now() - start_time) > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)):
                # we've been running for more than a minute
                if not l:
                    # There's nothing left in l; all jobs have (probably) finished
                    break

        out_tuple_list = out_results.get(timeout=300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Infrequently,* when I run this code, I get `multiprocessing.Timeout`s. This says to me that sometimes the result isn't ready to be read five minutes after the last result is removed from the shared not-quite-a-job-queue (the list `l`).

I've resorted to getting a shell in the interpreter with IPython when the Timeout is thrown. However, my experience with the multiprocessing library is somewhat limited. Here are some of the (less embarrassing) commands I've sent to IPython to try to determine what's going on:

```
In [2]: pool.join()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Documents/src/projects/my_proj/./main.py:29, in create_repo_img_tuple_issue_list_map(json_report_locations, cve_resolution_dict, manager)
    28 try:
--> 29     out_tuple_list = out_results.get(timeout=300)

    30 except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py:767, in ApplyResult.get(self, timeout)
    766 if not self.ready():
--> 767     raise TimeoutError
    768 if self._success:

TimeoutError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 pool.join()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py:659, in Pool.join(self)
    657 util.debug('joining pool')
    658 if self._state == RUN:
--> 659     raise ValueError("Pool is still running")
    660 elif self._state not in (CLOSE, TERMINATE):
    661     raise ValueError("In unknown state")

ValueError: Pool is still running

In [3]: pool
Out[3]: <multiprocessing.pool.Pool state=RUN pool_size=99>
...
In [7]: out_results.ready()
Out[7]: False

In [8]: pool._terminate
Out[8]: <Finalize object, callback=_terminate_pool, args=(<_queue.SimpleQueue object at 0x10eb5dd00>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x10eb39cc0>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x10eb3b340>, [<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' pid=21273 parent=21269 started daemon>, ...<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-113' pid=21386 parent=21269 started daemon>], <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x10eb39ba0>, <Thread(Thread-1 (_handle_workers), started daemon 123145420689408)>, <Thread(Thread-2 (_handle_tasks), started daemon 123145437478912)>, <Thread(Thread-3 (_handle_results), started daemon 123145454268416)>, {0: <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x10eb8dcf0>}), exitpriority=15>
...
In [11]: pool._terminate.still_active()
Out[11]: True
...
In [22]: all([p.is_alive() for p in pool._pool])
Out[22]: True
```

So it looks like all my processes are still alive.

## Question

How can I determine which process in the `multiprocessing.Pool` is preventing the pool from entering the finished state? Is there a way (in python3.10) to monitor why a process is preventing the pool from moving into the ready state?

### EDIT

I know there's a race condition here, but the jobs don't usually don't take 5 minutes to complete. I can also query the list `l` in the IPython shell and it's still empty.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10, [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) objects surface an [`exitcode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.exitcode) value that (should) signal if they're finished. The `exitcode` (and the code's corresponding `Process` object) can be determined as such:

```py
filter(lambda x: x.exitcode == None, pool._pool)
```